# ASP.NET Delete Multiple GridView rows via Checkbox template

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I have a GirdView table in my application. I have a **Delete** link button and a checkbox in my first column. Below are snapshots:

[image][image]

I can manually delete each row by clicking **Delete** link button on each row.

However, I would want to enable the checkbox to delete multiple rows.

Below is my code for my **Delete** link button:

```
LinkButton lnk = (LinkButton)sender; 
        string stid = lnk.CommandArgument.ToString();
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=DATASOURCE");
        string sql = string.Format("DELETE FROM [UserDB] where Employee like '%{0}%'",stid);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql,conn);
        conn.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Below is my code for the current **Delete Checked** button:

```
bool atLeastOneRowDeleted = false;
        foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
        {
            // Access the CheckBox
            CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("UserSelection");
            if (cb != null && cb.Checked)
            {
                atLeastOneRowDeleted = true;
                // How do I get the value from my Employee column?
                string userID = ???;


           SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=DATASOURCE");
           string sql = string.Format("DELETE FROM [UserDB] where Employee like '%{0}%'",userID);
           SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql,conn);
           conn.Open();
           cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
```

I would like to know how should I grep userID, which is `Employee` key in the GridView, to `INSERT` it into my SQL delete statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want

```
bool atLeastOneRowDeleted = false;
    foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
    {
        // Access the CheckBox
        CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("UserSelection");
        if (cb != null && cb.Checked)
        {
            atLeastOneRowDeleted = true;
            //assuming you have the ID column after the controls
            string CusId = (row.Cells[3].Text);


       SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=DATASOURCE");
       string sql = string.Format("DELETE FROM [UserDB] where Employee like '%{0}%'",userID);
       SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql,conn);
       conn.Open();
       cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
```

Comment: CBRRacer racer has a point that you'd be better of getting the keys and then doing one delete.  Otherwise you'll be blowing out a lot of uneeded sql.  And it will never scale.

Answer (score 1):

well without seeing your code for the checkboxes, I would say set the value of the checkboxes to the UserID of the employee. Then on submit set the checked values to a list or array and then parse that list or array with your delete single method.

Answer (score 0):

Using 'row.Cells[3].Text' to fetch column values is a bad way. If he adds another column in between then the index would change. Use dataKeys instead to reference your column values.

Answer (score 0):

This question has already been answered but here's an article which shows which entire flow using datbase, Gridview, Business Logic and DAL.

Final Preview looks something like this

[image]

You can find the entire source code [here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/1e050f/delete-records-from-gridview-using-checkbox-in-Asp-Net/)